# Вопрос по объекту style

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть такая проблема. Создаю класс в javascript. Там использую конструкцию вида:

```
this.display = function()
{
    var but = document.createElement('<div>');
    but.width = this.width;
    but.height = this.height;
    but.style.top = this.top + "px";
...
```

Но в firefox firebug выдает ошибку: типа свойство style не определено. В ie вроде нормально. Не знаете, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Уберите треугольные скобки вокруг div. =)